# What is the way to store "Time only" values with php?

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have a Mysql table which has a column **of type TIME**.

**When I retrieve the values of this TIME column with PHP, how should I store it in php variable for later use in my php classes?**

- Should I keep it as string : "12:45:23"?
- Should I convert it to a fraction of a day : 0.25 is 06:00:00 ?
- Should I convert it to a number of seconds : 15152 is 04:12:32 ?
- other?

I would like to use the standard php 5 way of dealing with time.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

My data is stored in a mysql table of type "TIME" and not "DATETIME".

I just want to deal with **time** (a number of hours, minutes and seconds). the date is NOT relevant in my case, so **unix timestamp** or date/time objects seems to not be appropriate.

Comment: i mostly use the unix timestamp

Comment: use whatever works for your application

Comment: My goodness, with the exception of one answer, all other answers are answering a different question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best and most common way is number of seconds as all php functions working in this format. Also see: "Unix timestamp"

Comment: A Unix timestamp also contains information about the date, and doesn't seem like an appropriate solution here.

Comment: @RoydeJong it's true, it would do to use unix timestamp.  But the 'elapsed seconds' method (which is also the base for the unix timestamps) is perfectly good for 'elapsed time' - or indeed 'time of day' (which is really just 'elapsed time since midnight')

Also; it's far better than 'HH;mm:ss' if you ever want to compare this 'elapsed time' :)

Answer (score 11):

Use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times), which is `hh:mm:ss` for better understanding, and high readbility

Comment: You mean that I should store it as a string with the ISO 8601 format?

Comment: Yup, there is nothing wrong with that, is very much depending on your application need, some answers suggesting timestamp obviously overkill, which is no ideal if your application is only dealing with hours. There is reason why mysql has date, datetime, timestamp, time...various data type is to cater for different purposes

Comment: @ajreal it's not great to do this if you ever need to compare this time.    "Elapsed seconds" is a lot more versatile IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Time is an interval, so you can store it as seconds.

The only thing is that seconds are not an object, and you can't give it handy functions, neither does it maintain the specific number of minutes provided.

For example say you use a time like `45:61:59`, after converting it to seconds you will not be able to convert it back to this format.

PHP solves these problems using `DateInterval`

`41:61:45` would be stored as

```
$interval = new DateInterval('PT41H61M45S');
```

The problem is that `DateInterval` is not as easy to use or useful as it could be, so why not create your own class?

Here, I created one just for you (or anyone looking)
(I know I'm late, but this question still pops up high in SERPs)

```php
class Time extends DateInterval {
    const SEC_IN_MINUTE = 60;
    const SEC_IN_HOUR = 3600;
    const SEC_IN_DAY = 86400;
    const SEC_IN_YEAR = 31536000;

    private $interval, $time;

    // takes an $time input of 48:23:12 or seconds or DateInterval spec
    public function __construct($time){
        // support interval spec format
        if (strpos($time, 'P') === 0) {
            parent::__construct($time);

        } else

        // support seconds
        if (is_int($time)) {
            parent::__construct('PT' . $time . 'S');

        } else
        // support 00:00:00 format
        if (preg_match('/([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/', $time, $match)) {
            $this->time = $time;
            $this->h = (int)$match[1];
            $this->i = (int)$match[2];
            $this->s = (int)$match[3];
            parent::__construct('PT' . $this->h . 'H' . $this->i . 'M' . $this->s . 'S');
        // support human format
        // e.g. "5 minutes"
        } elseif(strtotime($time)) {
            $dt = new DateTime('@0', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
            $dt->modify($time);
            parent::__construct('PT' . $dt->getTimeStamp() . 'S');
        }else {
            throw new Exception('"' . $time . '" is an unknown time format');
        }
    }
    public function toSeconds(){
        $zero = new DateTime('@0'); // zero date
        return $zero->add($this)->getTimestamp();
    }
    public function toMinutes(){
        return $this->toSeconds() / 60;
    }
    public function toHours(){
        return $this->toMinutes() / 60;
    }
    public function toDays(){
        return $this->toHours() / 24;
    }
    public function toYears(){
        return $this->toHours() / 365;
    }

    // recalculate carry over points
    // this is to convert a time like 22:98:74 to 23:39:14
    // warning: intervals don't know how long a month is, and as such can't support them
    public function recalculate()
    {
        $zero = new DateTime('@0'); // zero date
        $to = clone $zero;
        $to = $to->add($this);
        $diff = $zero->diff($to);
        foreach ($diff as $k => $v) $this->$k = $v;

        $dt = new DateTime('@0'); // zero date
        $dt->add(new self('P'.$this->m.'M'));
        $seconds = $dt->getTimeStamp();

        // add what was months to days
        $this->m = 0;
        $this->d += $seconds / 86400;

        // move excess days to years 
        if($this->d > 365){
            $this->y = floor($this->d / 365);
            $this->d = $this->d % 365;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    // remove all whole chunks of interval from seconds and return the amount of chunks
    protected function popTimeSpan(&$seconds, $interval){
        $timespan = $seconds / $interval;
        $timespan = floor($timespan);
        $seconds -= $timespan * $interval;
        return $timespan;
    }

    // a special version of format() that will maintain the full interval in the formatted string
    // warning: it does not support %m or %M, which will always be converted to 0
    public function reformat($format){

        $seconds = $this->toSeconds();


        if(strpos($format, '%y')!==false || strpos($format, '%Y')!==false){
            $timespan = self::popTimeSpan($seconds, self::SEC_IN_YEAR);
            $format = str_replace('%y', $timespan, $format);
            $format = str_replace('%Y', str_pad($timespan,4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT), $format);
        }
        if(strpos($format, '%m')!==false || strpos($format, '%M')!==false){
            $format = str_replace('%m', '0', $format);
            $format = str_replace('%M', '00', $format);
        }
        if(strpos($format, '%d')!==false || strpos($format, '%D')!==false){
            $timespan = self::popTimeSpan($seconds, self::SEC_IN_DAY);
            $format = str_replace('%d', $timespan, $format);
            $format = str_replace('%D', str_pad($timespan,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT), $format);
        }
        if(strpos($format, '%h')!==false || strpos($format, '%H')!==false){
            $timespan = self::popTimeSpan($seconds, self::SEC_IN_HOUR);
            $format = str_replace('%h', $timespan, $format);
            $format = str_replace('%H', str_pad($timespan,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT), $format);
        }
        if(strpos($format, '%i')!==false || strpos($format, '%I')!==false){
            $timespan = self::popTimeSpan($seconds, self::SEC_IN_MINUTE);
            $format = str_replace('%i', $timespan, $format);
            $format = str_replace('%I', str_pad($timespan,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT), $format);
        }
        if(strpos($format, '%s')!==false || strpos($format, '%S')!==false){
            $timespan = floor($seconds);
            $format = str_replace('%s', $timespan, $format);
            $format = str_replace('%S', str_pad($timespan,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT), $format);
        }

        return $this->format($format);
    }
}

$time = new Time('23:10:15');
echo 'Seconds: '.$time->s.'<br>'; // 15
echo 'toSeconds: '.$time->toSeconds().'<br>'; // 83415

// lets try with times that are above 24 hour
$time = new Time('48:10:16');
echo 'Seconds: '.$time->s.'<br>'; // 16
echo 'toSeconds: '.$time->toSeconds().'<br>'; // 173416

// lets try with times that are messy
$time = new Time('23:98:75');
echo 'Seconds: '.$time->s.'<br>'; // 75
echo 'toSeconds: '.$time->toSeconds().'<br>'; // 88755
echo 'Formatted: '.$time->format('%Y-%d %H:%i:%s').'<br>'; // 00-0 23:98:75
echo 'Recalculated: '.$time->reformat('%Y-%d %H:%i:%s').'<br>'; // 0000-1 00:39:15

// lets try with months!!
$time = new Time('13044:98:74');
echo 'Seconds: '.$time->s.'<br>'; // 74
echo 'toSeconds: '.$time->toSeconds().'<br>'; // 46964354
echo 'Formatted: '.$time->format('%Y-%d %H:%i:%s').'<br>'; //  00-0 13044:98:74
echo 'Recalculated: '.$time->reformat('%Y-%d %H:%i:%s').'<br>'; // 0001-178 13:39:14


// ok, now with years
$time = new Time('87630:98:74'); // 10 years, 30 hours 98 minutes  and 74 seconds
echo 'Time: 87630:98:74<br>';
echo 'Formatted at year level: '.$time->format('%Y-%d %H:%i:%s').'<br>'; // 00-0 87630:98:74
echo 'Formatted at day level: '.$time->format('%d %H:%i:%s').'<br>'; // 0 87630:98:74
echo 'Formatted at hour level: '.$time->format('%H:%i:%s').'<br>'; // 87630:98:74
echo 'Formatted at minute level: '.$time->format('%i:%s').'<br>'; // 98:74
echo 'Formatted at second level: '.$time->format('%s seconds').'<br>'; // 74 seconds
echo 'Formatted at year + second level: '.$time->format('%y years %s seconds').'<br>'; // 0 years 74 seconds

echo 'Recalculated at year level: '.$time->reformat('%Y-%d %H:%i:%s').'<br>'; // 0010-1 07:39:14
echo 'Recalculated at day level: '.$time->reformat('%d %H:%i:%s').'<br>'; // 3651 07:39:14
echo 'Recalculated at hour level: '.$time->reformat('%H:%i:%s').'<br>'; // 87631:39:14
echo 'Recalculated at minute level: '.$time->reformat('%i:%s').'<br>'; // 5257899:14
echo 'Recalculated at second level: '.$time->reformat('%s seconds').'<br>'; // 315473954 seconds
echo 'Recalculated at year + second level: '.$time->reformat('%y years %s seconds').'<br>'; // 10 years 113954 seconds

echo 'Test %a: '.$time->reformat('%a').'<br>'; // (unknown)
echo 'Test %R: '.$time->reformat('%r').'<br>'; // 
echo 'Test %r: '.$time->reformat('%R').'<br>'; // +
```

Now you can take that MySQL time and easily do whatever you want with it.

```php
$time = new Time('864:23:59');
$seconds = $time->toSeconds();
$formatted_time = $time->reformat('%d days %h:%i:%s');
```

Feel free to edit this and make it shorter or better

Answer (score 2):

In general you should always store a date/time value in the database's native date/time formats. This lets you use the DB's native date/time manipulation functions in queries. Otherwise it's just a chunk of text and you're stuck with using string manipulation, or having to select each time field and manipulating it in your app.

Comment: Then you can do `SELECT unix_timestamp(datetimefield)` which produces a simple signed integer value, which can be put into PHP's date/time functions directly.

Comment: There's the `time_to_sec()` mysql function for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "standard" - it really depends on your requirements.

However, if you need to store date/time information in a canonical format, I'd recommend using RFC2822 (`date('r')`) as this will ensure that it's always correct even when the timezone changes due to summer time, etc. if that's relevant.

If this isn't a consideration, then simply using a timestamp (a.k.a: unixtime - the output of `time()`) may well prove sufficient as this can be trivially converted between the native MySQL datetime format. (Use [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert within PHP or simply use the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) or [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) MySQL functions within the SQL query.)

Answer (score 2):

The unix timestamp is probably the best for most common use, since it is also compatible with all the PHP date/time function and is smaller in size than a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options you have.

PHP has a nice function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) that can parse a lot of different formats. So if you wanted to keep the time readable you could.

Most often, however, the time format is stored as the number of seconds since the [Unix epoch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php). Saves trouble of having to constantly parse again.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Date/Time classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). Many of them got most of their usefulness at 5.3, so if you're stuck below that, they won't help you much.